# Datatables + angular.js + xeditable is not working

Tags: angularjs, datatable, x-editable

I am using angular with Datatables and I am trying to edit a row with Xeditable, my issue is that there are no xeditables elements, the span is not turning into editable span.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="dataTables_wrapper">
        <table datatable="ng" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" role="grid">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{texts.fullName}}</th>
            <th>{{texts.title}}</th>
            <th>{{texts.email}}</th>
            <th>edit</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index">
            <td>
                {{contact.fullName}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{contact.title}}
            </td>
            <td>
              <span editable-text="contact.email" e-name="email" e-form="rowform">
                {{ contact.email || 'empty' }}
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <!-- form -->
    <form editable-form name="rowform" onbeforesave="saveUser($data, user.id)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline">
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">
        save
      </button>
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">
        cancel
      </button>
    </form>
    <div class="buttons" ng-show="!rowform.$visible">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rowform.$show()">edit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeUser($index)">del</button>
    </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I can see that the xeditable code can't find the $editables elements, I thought it is related to datatable because if I'm trying to use regular table it works well.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Best,
Omri

Answer (score 0):

Your `editable-text` isn't in the `editable-form`, this might be the problem.
I think the following code would fix it.

```
 <form editable-form name="rowform" onbeforesave="saveUser($data, user.id)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline">
      <span editable-text="contact.email" e-name="email" e-form="rowform">
          {{ contact.email || 'empty' }
      </span>
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">
          save
      </button>
      <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">
          cancel
      </button>
</form>
```